# Python elif Statement acting unconditional

Tags: python

Not sure why my code is defaulting to this elif.  But it's never getting to the else statement.  Even going as far as throwing index out of bound errors in the last elif.

Please disregard my non use of regex.  It wasn't allowed for this homework assignment.  The problem is the last elif before the else statement.

```
if item == '':
    print ("%s\n" % item).rstrip('\n')

elif item.startswith('MOVE') and not item.startswith('MOVEI'):
    print 'Found MOVE'

elif item.startswith('MOVEI'):
    print 'Found MOVEI'

elif item.startswith('BGT'):
    print 'Found BGT'

# ...

elif item.find(':') and item[(item.find(':') -1)].isalpha():
    print 'Mya have found a label'

else:
    # Never get to this branch
    print 'Not sure what I found'
```

Comment: Be careful with your indentation when posting Python code..

Comment: Good point.  My apologies on that one.

Comment: You can fix it by clicking the "edit" link below your question.

Comment: What is the test data in item you are validating?

Answer (score 4):

`item.find(':')` will return `-1` when "`:`" is not found in `item`.

`-1` is evaluated as being `True`-ish, so this is likely the source of your problem. `if item.find(':')` will not be matched only if "`:`" is at the beginning of `item`.

To solve the problem, just replace this line:

```
elif item.find(':') and item[(item.find(':') -1)].isalpha():
```

with this line:

```
elif ':' in item and item[item.find(':') - 1].isalpha():
```

Which effectively will check, if the char preceding "`:`" is alphanumeric.

Comment: Hmm ok.  So how would I recraft that statement to find ':' in the string and check to see if the character before that is alpha?

Comment: @BradCarvalho: See the updated answer. You just need to change that `find` part to compare with `-1`. If result of `find()` will be equal to `-1` that means, that the string has not been found. Otherwise it will get you the position. Just remember, that if `find()` returns `0`, `:` is located at the beginning of the string and as a result, you will be checking if the last character (located at `-1` position, so first from the end) is alpha.

Comment: @BradCarvalho: No problem, you are welcome. Instead of doing `item.find(':') != -1` you can also do `':' in item`, which is shorter, clearer and more pythonic.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: You are right about `:` being at the beginning of the string - I mentioned it in the comments, also Blender added information about it. However, there will be no exception (if you are talking about actual Python exceptions that can be raised and caught) unless there is something more in this code.

Comment: instead of trying to use `.find` and calculating an index, consider using `.partition` to take the string apart around the colon.

Answer (score 3):

- Your `if` case is really strange:

  ```
  print ("%s\n" % item).rstrip('\n')
  ```

  If `item == ''`, `(item + '\n').rstrip('\n')` will be equal to `item`, which is `''`. I'm pretty sure you can get rid of that code.
- Reordering your `if` statements can remove the `MOVEI`/`MOVE` problem.
- Adding on to [Tadeck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444174/464744), you need to use `item.find(':') > 0` as your condition. If your string starts with `:`, `string[0 - 1] == string[-1]`, which is the *last* character of your string.

Here's a possibly fixed version of the code

```
if item == '':
    print ''
elif item.startswith('MOVEI'):
    print 'Found MOVEI'
elif item.startswith('MOVE'):
    print 'Found MOVE'
elif item.startswith('BGT'):
    print 'Found BGT'
elif item.startswith('ADD'):
    print 'Found ADD'
elif item.startswith('INC'):
    print 'Found INC'
elif item.startswith('SUB'):
    print 'Found SUB'
elif item.startswith('DEC'):
    print 'Found DEC'
elif item.startswith('MUL'):
    print 'Found MUL'
elif item.startswith('DIV'):
    print 'Found DIV'
elif item.startswith('BEQ'):
    print 'Found BEQ'
elif item.startswith('BLT'):
    print 'Found BLT'
elif item.startswith('BR'):
    print 'Found BR'
elif item.startswith('END'):
    print 'Found END'
elif item.find(':') > 0 and item[(item.find(':') - 1)].isalpha():
    print 'Mya have found a label'
else:
    print 'Not sure what I found'
```

---

Here's a slightly more Pythonic version of your code:

```
def test_item(item):
  tests = ['MOVEI', 'MOVE', 'BGT', 'ADD', 'INC', 'SUB', 'DEC', 'MUL', 'DIV', 'BEQ', 'BLT', 'BR', 'END']

  for test in tests:
    if item.startswith(test):
      return 'Found ' + test

  if item.find(':') > 0 and item[(item.find(':') - 1)].isalpha():
    return 'Mya have found a label'
  else:
    return 'Not sure what I found'
```

Comment: +1 That is right. We could also shorten the code (by converting all these "`startswith`" conditions into one) if this is all it does. But I believe what we don't see (the other code) contains more problems, so I gave the solution only to the problem OP reported. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: I like what you did there.  However, those print "Found" statements are just placeholders for additional checks I need to do based on the starts with match.  Each of them are different checks as well.